# How does isosurface() do the default lighting in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

According to the documentation, if `isosurface()` is called with no output arguments and there is no current axes, Matlab will create an axes and add lighting to the graph.

I want to render my 3D array to a GUI axes. How can I add light and set the properties of the axes so that it behaves similar to calling isosurface without output arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a function that behaves like `isosurface()` you can take a look at how it's done in it. You can do so by entering `edit isosurface` in the Matlab console.

The part regarding the light when there is no axes is this one:

```
  if isempty(ax)
    view(3); 
    camlight; lighting gouraud
  end
```